# ElasticSearch Match Query Fuzziness

Tags: elasticsearch, nest

I'm running into a problem when searching with fuzziness in a match query. The name I want to find is "Şaban Dişli", as seen in the below, I am querying. But I am not getting results for some queries even though I am always two away. Can you help me with this?

I also use the asciifolding token filter structure.

```
//correct result is coming.
GET analyze5/_search
{
  "query": {
    
    "bool": {
    
      "should": [
        {
          "match": {
            "fullName": {
              "fuzziness": 2,
              "operator": "AND",
              "query": "şaban dişli"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },"size":10000
}
```

```
//correct result is coming.
GET analyze5/_search
{
  "query": {
    
    "bool": {
    
      "should": [
        {
          "match": {
            "fullName": {
              "fuzziness": 2,
              "operator": "AND",
              "query": "caban dacli"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },"size":10000
}
```

```
//correct result is coming.
GET analyze5/_search
{
  "query": {
    
    "bool": {
    
      "should": [
        {
          "match": {
            "fullName": {
              "fuzziness": 2,
              "operator": "AND",
              "query": "mvban dişli"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },"size":10000
}
```

```
//no results are coming.
GET analyze5/_search
{
  "query": {
    
    "bool": {
    
      "should": [
        {
          "match": {
            "fullName": {
              "fuzziness": 2,
              "operator": "AND",
              "query": "abban dişli"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },"size":10000

}
```

```
//correct result
{
        "_index" : "analyze5",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "2183101",
        "_score" : 17.339989,
        "_source" : {
          "id" : 2183101,
          "fullName" : "Şaban DİŞLİ",
      
        }
      }
```

Comment: "operator": You can change "AND" to Operator "OR".